# JCR Repository available for Junit tests

Tags: content-management-system, junit, osgi, jackrabbit, jcr

I have a code accessing to content repositories through JCR API. My code is being developed in OSGI environment. What I want is to have a JCR content repository which should be available while running the unit tests regardless from the environment. I mean it should be available for any user who builds the project. I don't want to depend on some external content repository running in a different virtual machine.

Is it possible to do such a thing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also look at the  transient repository provided by the Jackrabbit implementation.
(assuming you are using Jackrabbit implementation)
A Transient Repository is

> a repository proxy that automatically initializes and shuts down the underlying repository instance when the first session is opened or the last one closed. 
>   - [API doc](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.0/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/TransientRepository.html)

Please look at the examples [here](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/first-hops.html) -  it is really easy to create an instance of it. Since it is a local repository, you will never need to go over the network.

I normally create a transient repository and a session once per JUnit test class in *setUpClass/BeforeClass hook*  and reuse it across all the test cases, cleaning up the session ( e.g, removing the nodes I added during a test case, etc.) after each test case.

One drawback, however, using transient repository, is that it will create several repository specific files/directory in your base directory. If you are using maven, then you can use [*maven-clean-plugin*](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html) to clean up the unwanted files as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Sling's [RepositoryTestBase](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/commons/testing/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/commons/testing/jcr/RepositoryTestBase.java) class provides a repository that can be used in "unit" testing. It does have some Sling dependencies, so you might not be able to use it as is but it's probably a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

ModeShape can easily be used within unit tests, and for unit tests our [In-Memory connector](http://docs.jboss.org/modeshape/latest/manuals/reference/html_single/reference-guide-en.html#in-memory-connector) and [Disk connector](http://docs.jboss.org/modeshape/latest/manuals/reference/html_single/reference-guide-en.html#disk-connector) work great and are very fast (and the in-memory doesn't require cleanup after each test). Our [JcrEngineTest](https://github.com/ModeShape/modeshape/blob/master/modeshape-jcr/src/test/java/org/modeshape/jcr/JcrEngineTest.java) shows how easy this is, with each method configuring and starting an engine instance within a few lines. Many of these test [complete in under 100ms](http://hudson.qa.jboss.com/hudson/view/ModeShape/job/ModeShape%20continuous/lastCompletedBuild/testReport/org.modeshape.jcr/JcrEngineTest/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TransientRepository` with a `MemoryFileSystem` and an [In-Memory PM](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.4/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/persistence/mem/InMemPersistenceManager.html) or a database persistence manager which can hanlde in-memory databases like [H2](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.2/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/persistence/pool/H2PersistenceManager.html).